# Deploying Postgresql with Golang on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I'm dealing with Kubernetes. It is not possible to connect the server and the database. Tell me what I'm doing wrong and what else I need to do.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: testdb
      app: testapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testdb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: testdb
          image: pryby/testdbcon
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: pryby/testdocker
          env:
            - name: LISTEN
              value: 0.0.0.0:8080
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: testdb
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: DB_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: DB_DBNAME
              value: postgres
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: DB_SSL
              value: disable
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

What and where do I need to specify in order to get access to the database?
If possible, give an example for working with the database and api, I climbed everywhere where I can, I didn't find anything like that. Maybe I didn't search well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Here in your testDB deployment your `selector`'s `match labels` and `template`'s `label` need to be the same.

Secondly, You need to create a `Service` of Type `ClusterIP`.

Here is the example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testdb
  labels:
    app: testdb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testdb
```

The final yaml should look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # tier: testdb
      app: testdb # <- *****changed here******
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testdb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: testdb
          image: pryby/testdbcon
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: pryby/testdocker
          env:
            - name: LISTEN
              value: 0.0.0.0:8080
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: testdb
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: DB_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: DB_DBNAME
              value: postgres
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: DB_SSL
              value: disable
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testdb
  labels:
    app: testdb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testdb
```

Comment: this is how it works, but the example of your Service does not work( everything falls flat and cannot access the database
`kubectl expose deployment testdb --port 5432 --target-port 5432 --name testdb`

Comment: it turned out like, once the server crashes, then tries to start again and works. Thanks

Comment: @Pryby That because you have created both deployment at a time. You need to create the `testDb` first then after the `testDB` is ready to accept connections, you can create the server. this time it will work., Actually this is happening because of the logic behind the server you have.

Answer (score 0):

expose your testdb deployment with a service of type ClusterIP and port 5432.

either craft the yaml yourself, or run `kubectl expose deployment testdb --port 5432 --targetPort 5432 --name testdb`

you can also use the following command to generate the yaml definition file:

```
kubectl expose deployment testdb --port 5432 --targetPort 5432 --name testdb -dry-run=client -o yaml > service-definition.yaml
```

Comment: I created yaml, right?
`kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: testapp
    tier: testdb
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432`

Comment: your advice helped, thank you. I will figure out how to do this through yaml

Comment: edited the answer with the command to generate the yaml for you. 
upvote/accept if it helps would be greatly appreciated